# Troposkein or troposkien?

Tags: spelling

I found two different spellings (troposkein and troposkien) in different resources, which one should I use in the context of VAWT (of Darrieus type),  and what is the difference?

Comment: Google detect "troposkien" as a misspelled word.

Comment: Yes it does, but "troposkien" still used by many researchers, even in some books.

Comment: Ahh, people often misspell a word with "ie" and "ei". I think it's just an unfortunate typo.

Comment: As an aside, there is also a [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/), so perhaps they would be able to help you as well?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troposkein

Comment: I've *ALREADY* visited Wikipedia !!!

Comment: If you’ve already looked it up in Wikipedia, and you’ve encountered alternate spellings in credible sources, then you should **include that information in your question**. It sounds like you already know more about this than most of us do, so why have all of us start from scratch and do research you’ve already done? Links to alternate spellings would be a big help. I recommend that you read through our entire [_Details, Please_ meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) to get a better idea of how to write a better question.

Answer (score 1):

The root word is [skein](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/skein) - a length of wool or thread collected together into the shape of a loose ring.

This would suggest that the correct spelling is troposkein.